# Why can't operator.eq be applied to a class map object using functools.reduce?

Tags: python

Why is the following Python code invalid?

```
iterable = [1, 2, 3]

mapped = map(operator.eq, iterable)
print(type(mapped)) # `class map`

functools.reduce(operator.eq, mapped)
```

A class `map` object is iterable. The following will work,

<sub>but produces (perhaps) "unexpected" results:</sub>

```
functools.reduce(operator.eq, iterable)
```

<sub>For example, applying this to the iterable `iterable = [True, False, False]` produces `True` not `False`. It is obvious why if you think about each iteration, but on a first glance it might look like it behaves in a different way.</sub>

---

If `functools.reduce` can apply a binary function `operator.eq` to the iterable `iterable`, why can it not apply the same function to the iterable `mapped` which is of type `class map`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually caused by `map` not by `reduce`.

The failure comes from

```
map(operator.eq, iterable)
```

which does not work because `map` can only map a unary function to the `iterable`.

If a pair of iterables are provided, then a binary function can be applied using `map`.

```
map(
    operator.eq,
    iterable[:-1],
    iterable[1:],
)
```